# Sublime Text 2 - Preventing from creating ._ files

Tags: sublimetext

Sublime Text 2 - when working on a network drive it create ._ files, and I can't seem to find a settings to turn this feature off.

I had similar problem with TextMate before and the solution was to change OakDocumentDisableFSMetaData property, but I can't find anything similar within Sublime

TextMate solution was:

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDocumentDisableFSMetaData 1
```

http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309913111/preventing-textmate-from-creating-files-on-network-drive

Answer (score 5):

Just add ._* to the file_exclude_patterns in your Sublime Preferences.
Or if you don't want it to be overwritten by further updates add this line to your User Prefs

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "._*"]
```

Comment: That only stops the files from being visible in sublime. It doesn't stop sublime from creating the files.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert it´s not a problem of Sublime. this files are creating by your OS :)

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Sorry you are wrong!

You can't avoid them. They're created to store file information that would otherwise go into an extended attribute on HFS+ (Apple native) or Unix/UFS volumes; in earlier Mac OS this would be the resource fork. Finder file operations will create them automatically to store the icon information, plus Time Machine stores some information in them so if you copy a file backed up via TM it will have that information copied as well.

Comment: Developers were told to stop using resource forks before OS X came out. Naitive OS X APIs were never created to access resource forks, only rhe carbon API for porting OS 9 apps to OS X can be used to access resource forks. I'm not sure about icons but time machine doesn't use resource forks. It has a central database at the root of the filesystem.